# Default argument holding function pointer

Tags: python, python-2.7, closures

Consider you have a class A - this example is for illustration only.
I want to be able to get as default parameter one of the methods in class.

1. I thought of writing something like code below, but its not possible, how can I achieve it correctly?
   I may want sometimes to call `self.foo2(foo3)`
2. Do we have a limit to do `self.foo2(foo2)` ?- I don't need to do that but just curious.

```
class A(object):
    def foo1(self):
        print "foo"
    def foo2(self,func_to_launch = self.foo1):
        #Doing something special1
        func_to_launch()
        #Doing something special2
    def foo3(self):
        print "foo special"
```

Comment: Parameters to functions (including `self`) are not available as variables when *defining* the function. In the dupe, the OP tried to do the same for the class name (which doesn't exist yet either). Only when the function is *called* is `self` available, so use a sentinel value for the default, then *inside* the function you can refer to `self.foo1`.

Comment: Also, when defining the class (including the methods of that class) there are no instances yet for `self` to refer to, and there is nothing for the `foo1` method to be bound to either. You have to wait until there is a `self` object to bind *to*.